# Simple groups in Jordan-Holder decomposition

Tags: group-theory

I have a group of order $1034 = 2\cdot11\cdot47$ and I need to find all simple groups in Jordan-Holder decomposition of this group. I know that there is only one $47$-Sylow subgroup with $46$ elements in it and only one $11$-Sylow subgroup with $10$ elements. So, we have a maximal normal subgroup of order $46$ (call it $H$) and hence $G\vartriangleleft H$. Now I'm stuck. $11$-Sylow subgroup is also abelian, so I need to prove that it is a subgroup of H. Or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started well. Let's say $P$ is the only $47$-Sylow subgroup and $Q$ is the only $11$-Sylow subgroup. Since at least one of the groups is normal (in our case actually both are normal) we know that $PQ$ is also a subgroup of $G$. From an isomorphism theorem it also follows that $|PQ|=\frac{|P||Q|}{|P\cap Q|}$. Since the intersection is trivial (why?) we conclude that $|PQ|=|P||Q|=517$. So this group has index $2$, hence it is normal in $G$. And now we get a chain of normal subgroups:

$\{e\}\trianglelefteq P\trianglelefteq PQ\trianglelefteq G$

And note that all quotient groups in this chain are simple as they are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2},\mathbb{Z_{11}},\mathbb{Z_{47}}$. So this is a Jordan-Holder decomposition and we found the simple quotient groups.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i have a question: Order of $47$-Sylow subgroup is 47? Not 46?

Comment: No. By definition, if $G$ is a group of order $p^rm$ where $p$ is a prime, $r\geq 1$ and $m$ is an integer which is not divisible by $p$ then a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is a subgroup of order $p^r$.